# get_absolute_url is NOT working on the combined queryset, How can l do it?

Tags: django, url, view, django-templates, model

I want to use `get_absolute_url` but it shows nothing on the **combined queryset**

It returns an error that:
*Page not found*
Below are my codes

```
#Action/models.py

class Action(models.Model): 
......
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('act',args=[self.slug])






#adventure/models.py


class Adventure(models.Model): 

......

def get_absolute_url(self):

   return reverse('adves',args=[self.slug])







#racing/models.py

class Racing(models.Model): 
......
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('act',args=[self.slug])





#puzzle/models.py

class Puzzle(models.Model): 
......
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('puz',args=[self.slug])
```

Then view of my **combined queryset**

```
#Others/views.py
from itertools import chain
def games(request):
...  .....

 act_games=Action.objects.all()
 adv_games=Adventure.objects.all()
 puz_games=Puzzle.objects.all()
 rac_games=Racing.objects.all()

 games=  list(chain(act_games,adv_games,puz_games,rac_games))
 context={
 'games':games,
}
 return render(request,'combined.html', context)
```

```
#combined.html
.......

{% for game in games %}
<div class="col">
<a href="{{ game.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ game.game_name }} </a>
{% endfor %}

.....
```

**My Expections**

When I refleshed the page l found no error. But when I tried clicking on the **link**,

It returned an error that

**Page not found**

Now l would like to know how make it pass successfully and take me to the slug link added when creating the object. **E.g**

When clicking on the action game on the **combined page** when it was created in the **Action models**  it must redirect me to the **slug link page** but just returns me **404 Page not found**

**Someone requested for the Urls so I decided to add these part too**

```
#Action/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def act(request, description):
 description=get_object_or_404(Action, slug=description)
 Context={'description': description}
 return render(request, 'description.html', Context)


#action/url.py

path('action', views.action, name='action'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.act, name='act' )
```

```
#Adventure/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def adv(request, description):
 description=get_object_or_404(Adventure, slug=description)
 Context={'description': description}
 return render(request, 'description.html', Context)


#adventure/url.py

path('adventure', views.adventure, name='adventure'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.adv, name='adv' )
```

```
#puzzle/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def puz(request, description):
 description=get_object_or_404(Puzzle, slug=description)
 Context={'description': description}
 return render(request, 'description.html', Context)


#puzzle/url.py

path('puzzle', views.puzzle, name='puzzle'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.puz, name='puz')
```

```
#Racing/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def rac(request, description):
 description=get_object_or_404(Action, slug=description)
 Context={'description': description}
 return render(request, 'description.html', Context)


#Racing/url.py

path('racing', views.racing, name='racing'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.rac, name='rac')
```

**That is it , seek ur help please**

Comment: Your `Racing` uses a view named '`act'`?

Comment: The **act** is the view for the description page. That when you click on the link it directs you the description. So t, no

Comment: Can you also share urls.py?

Comment: Okay let me edit my question and add on the URLs

Comment: I have added ,them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paths are overlapping. Indeed, for adventures and puzzles, the URLs are:

```
path('adventure', views.adventure, name='adventure'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.adv, name='adv')
path('puzzle', views.puzzle, name='puzzle'),
path('description/<slug:description>/', views.puz, name='puz')
```

so imagine that the URL is `description/adv-slug`, then which path should Django take? It will always take the first one, so in this case `adv`, even if there is no such slug. As a result a lot of URLs, generated for puzzles, will not work.

Even if that would work, if an `Adventure` and `Puzzle` object would somehow have the same slug, then another problem would arise: that both paths are valid.

You therefore better make non-overlapping URLs, like:

```
# adventure/url.py

path('adventure', views.adventure, name='adventure'),
path('adventure/<slug:description>/', views.adv, name='adv')

# puzzle/url.py

path('puzzle', views.puzzle, name='puzzle'),
path('puzzle/<slug:description>/', views.puz, name='puz')
```

You should also update your `Racing` model:

```
class Racing(models.Model):
    # …
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rac', args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: Thanks , you have solved me, it have worked. Everything was fine only that issue. Thanks very much